# Cómo pasar una propiedad de un elemento visual como parámetro de un converter en un binding de XAML

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, ivalueconverter

Tengo un problema en Xamarin al hacer un binding, utilizando un converter. Quiero pasar una propiedad del propio elemento visual como parámetro del converter, porque para mi aplicación sería más correcto hacerlo así.

En concreto quiero hacer un binding hacia la propiedad `Threshold` de un `SwipeView`, pero el resultado depende del número de elementos del `SwipeView`, o más concretamente del elemento `SwipeItems` asignado a la propiedad `SwipeView.LeftItems`.

¿Esto es posible de alguna manera o debo buscar alternativas como hacerlo por código, o pasar el propio elemento al converter?

Ejemplo de código mínimo de lo que quiero hacer y no consigo.

```xml
<SwipeView x:Name="SwipeLeft"
           Threshold="{Binding Width, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}, ConverterParameter={Reference SwipeLeftItems.¿Count?}, Source={Reference SwipeLeft}}">
    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
        <SwipeItems x:Name="SwipeLeftItems">
            <SwipeItemView>
                ...
            </SwipeItemView>
            ...
            <SwipeItemView>
                ...
            </SwipeItemView>
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
</SwipeView>
```

Cabe destacar que el número de elementos del swipe puede variar en tiempo de ejecución, y es por esto que necesito pasar el número de elementos al converter.

La parte que no tengo clara es cómo lograr lo que he escrito como `ConverterParameter={Reference SwipeLeftItems.¿Count?}`, o siquiera si es posible en XAML sin pasar el objeto `SwipeItems` entero al converter, ya que solo quiero pasar un entero, para que de esta forma el converter sea reutilizable en otras zonas de la aplicación, con otro tipo de elementos visuales.

Answer (score 0):

Tras mucho buscar en la documentación, **no he encontrado ninguna manera de acceder a una propiedad de un elemento visual para pasarlo como parámetro de un converter**.

Lo que sí se podría hacer es pasar un elemento visual al que se le haya dado un nombre con `x:Name`, que no es lo que busco, ya que eso reduciría la reutilización del *converter*.

Sin embargo, he encontrado una forma de **lograr un efecto similar**, que comparto para quien esté en una situación similar.

Dado que voy a dividir un ancho en base a 2 valores, podemos pensar que el segundo, más que un parámetro modificador de la conversión, es un dependencia de la propia conversión.

Con esto en mente, podemos pensar en utilizar ***multi bindings***, junto con un *multi value converter*, que además tiene la ventaja de que cada elemento *binding* puede tener su propia fuente, y tenemos acceso a la propiedad `Path`, lo que nos permite acceder al número de elementos de una colección, y pasarlo como entero al *converter*, esta vez no como parámetro, sino como elemento de igual importancia que los demás valores, que en este caso serían 2.

```xml
<SwipeView x:Name="SwipeLeft">
    <SwipeView.Threshold>
        <MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource WidthMultiConverter}>
            <Binding Path="Width" Source="{x:Reference SwipeLeft}" />
            <Binding Path="Count" Source="{x:Reference SwipeLeftItems}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </SwipeView.Threshold>
    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
        <SwipeItems x:Name="SwipeLeftItems">
            <SwipeItemView>
                ...
            </SwipeItemView>
            ...
            <SwipeItemView>
                ...
            </SwipeItemView>
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
</SwipeView>
```